# Why the objective function and some constraints doesn't labeled as indexed in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, gekko

I have modeled a mathematical optimization problem into pyomo Python as bellow.
I do not understand why just my "constraint2" is labeled as "indexed" in pyomo?
Is that affect the problem solving? Cause I use "ipopt" as solver but my results seems much different when I use "Gekko" library and the same "ipopt" solver.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each constraint labeled as `indexed constraint ` means that it whether is the same constraint that applied for differents indexes (like x_i >=0 for all i in K) or is a Constraint list where you have different constraints and those are numbered by an index. This is irrelevant for the solving process but, means a great improvement in modelling. I don't know what is affecting the results of this problem. Sorry

Comment: Could you post both the pyomo and gekko code with your question?